# How do I get web analytics on traffic to my firebase app?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, statistics, firebase-hosting

Do I need to build it into the app, or does firebase gather stats on how many users open the app and associated links? Thanks

Comment: Your questions seem to be about Firebase Hosting. Please tag them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting does not have built in analytics that you can access.

If you want to add a third-party in-page analytics tool to your pages, there are tons of those to choose from. Recommending such products is off-topic for StackOverflow though.

Comment: I think that listing possibilities as objectively as possible should not be off-topic.